# How to buy Air conditioner?

Tags: bedroom

We are planning to buy AC for our small bed room for this summar. I am really confused with the specification described in the show room. 
What does it mean 1.5 ton AC ??
What is that rechargeable fan ??
What is the main thing do I need to check while buying AC ??
My question may be simple . but please guide me .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Air conditioners are rated in tons, how many tons of ice they could produce in 24 hours. The higher tonnage the more cold air or larger area they can cool. Rechargeable fan? Is this 2 words rechargeable meaning it has a port to allow a recharge of the "freon" many use R134a today, but a good unit should last for years as long as the filters are regularly cleaned.

Comment: "Tons" of cooling is a silly measurement. Basically one ton = 12,000 BTU's. A BTU is the amount of heat it takes to heat (or cool) one pound (or one pint) of water one degree Fahrenheit. Most heating (but not cooling, go figure) is measured in BTU's per hour. BTU's are almost as silly but we are stuck with them. Heating and cooling load calculations (in the US anyway) are done in BTU's. We just switch everything to calories and be done with it.

Comment: Not 1 pound of ice 1 ton in 24 hours

Comment: Watch out for control panels with bubble buttons: http://www.mpja.com/Keypad-16-Button-X-Y-Peel-N-Stick/productinfo/31046+SW/ If one goes bad, replacement cost is usually as much as a new air conditioner. Old fashioned switches and knobs have a lower failure rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your "small" bedroom is at least 111-square meters 1.5 ton is way too large, that would need a wiring upgrade & would suck money right out of your pocket. You'd want something in the .5 ton range (not 1-plus anything).

If you'd like a rechargeable fan for frequent power outages & it's common amongst your selection, then you'll have something to move the air. So, that's a plus but a waste & a potential future problem if you don't see a need.

The store(s) should have a sheet, pamphlet or booklet with the "approximate" size AC unit for a range of room sizes. .5ton or 6000btu should likely work perfectly, but get the store chart, measure your room & go for the next size up or for the maximum suggested for that room size. Going too big does cool, but it doesn't remove the humidity before it shuts off, so you'll always feel clammy.

Comment: Any size will remove the humidity . I do agree 1.5 ton is large for a small bedroom but the question was what do the numbers mean.

Comment: Ed, that's how I started & finished my answer. Do you have a better suggestion for an answer or what I could re-word for someone who "might" think a whopping 1200-sqft is a SMALL bedroom?

Comment: I think the 1.5T number simply came from something she saw at the dealer. I hardly think anyone was suggesting 1.5T for a small bedroom. And who ever suggested this was a 1200sq/ft BR???

Comment: I did, since 1.5ton is about an 18,000btu unit & would be for a room of somewhere about that size. That's why I suggested she measure & get calculator from the store, hopefully talking to someone there so she doesn't take a fridge home for a closet.

Comment: Thanks loggy, for the useful information and your valuable answer

Comment: No problem at all. The store should be able to guide you accurately with your measurements & by even factoring in if you get full Sun exposure on the room or its windows.